# Notification of Re-Opened Questions?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, reopen-closed

Is there a way to be notified if someone's question is re-opened?  Occasionally I'll be in the middle of composing an answer when the question is closed.  Sometimes I'll agree with the community's decision to close the question, sometimes I won't (and will nominate it for re-opening, including maybe an edit and/or a helpful comment to try to get the user to repair the question).

The question may be re-opened at some later time, and I'll be in a position to answer it.  (Hopefully the auto-saved partially composed answer is still auto-saved.)  But this could be hours or even days later.

Is there a means I don't know about whereby I can be notified that it was re-opened?  If not, can such a feature be added?  Maybe some kind of "notify me of changes to this question" link/button/element that would just pop something into my Stack Exchange inbox when the question is edited/re-opened/deleted/migrated, or in some other way generates a similar notification to its owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the usefulness as far as convenience goes in your idea. However, I think this is a bit of a corner case. While it is not altogether *uncommon* for a question to be re-opened, it typically only happens if:

- The question was closed by the community, a moderator or both erroneously. The scenario here is usually closing something as a duplicate that really isn't a duplicate. That *does* happen, but in the grand scheme of the number of questions closed every day, it doesn't happen often.
- The question is sufficiently improved to warrant re-opening. In the ~10 months I've been moderating, I can't recall more than a few times that happened. Two of the specific events I'm recalling also involved extensive editing help from several moderators.

As such, closing is generally a one way street. However, there *are* other features you can use. As Jeremy said, you can favorite it. You can also simply leave a *comment* to the original author and ask to be pinged if the question is re-opened and they still need an answer. If the OP really cares about the question and needs it answered, they'll work to get it re-opened and ping you. Then, you'll have your inbox notification.

Again, I'm not saying you have a bad idea, I just wonder if its usefulness might be a bit too narrowly scoped when other means exist.

Answer (score 2):

> If not, can such a feature be added? Maybe some kind of "notify me of changes to this question" link/button/element that would just pop something into my Stack Exchange inbox when the question is edited/re-opened/deleted/migrated, or in some other way generates a similar notification to its owner?

Starring/favoriting a question serves this purpose. It doesn't generate inbox notifications, but when you view your profile there are the same indicators for activity on starred questions   as there are for changes in reputation. I'm not certain, but I think that re-opening a question would trigger this.

[image]